# Proving that order of a cyclic group $G$ is divisible by a number

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Suppose that $\exists x,s.t. |x|=20$ and $\exists y,s.t. |y|=16$ and $x,y \in G$ where $G$ is a cyclic group.

How can I show that order of $G$ is divisible by 80?

I was thinking of using the fact that "$G$ is a finite cyclic group and $b\in G$ means that $|b|$ divides order of $G$. But not sure how to apply it in this context.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $5|20|n=|G|$ and $16|n$ and $(5,16)=1$, $5\cdot 16|n$.

Comment: How do you get $5(16) | n$?

Comment: Because $5$ divides $n$ and so does $16$, so their least common multiple must also divide $n$. But $5$ and $16$ are coprime, so $\text{lcm}(5,16)=80$ divides $n$.

Comment: Is that a general fact? That if $a | n$ and $b |n$ then their least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ i.e. $lcm(a,b)$ must divide $n$? And thank you I got it!

Comment: Yes, this is by definition: $m$ is the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$, if, for any integer $c$ s.t. $a|c$ and $b|c$, we have $m|c$.

Comment: Is there a condition that $gcd(a,b)=1$? Because otherwise, we could take $lcm(16,20)=80$ and say that $80$ divides $n$ right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mentioned the $\text{gcd}$ because it makes it clear that the least common multiple of $5$ and $16$ is their product. But your argument is more elegant if this is already clear on its own.

Comment: Ahh, I see I get it! Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint. A cyclic group is abelian. What can you say about the order of $xy$?

Comment: My book uses a corollary that the order of $xy$ must divide order of $x$ times order of $y$,i.e. $|xy|$ divides $|x||y|$. But I'm not sure if this helps.. Because it doesn't have anything to do with the order of $G$..

Comment: Your book probably has a stronger conclusion than that. But don't look for it. Just imagine writing down the sequence of powers $xy, x^2y^2, x^3y^3, \ldots$ and see where you will reach the identity.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I don't think my book talked about it yet. But answer, below used elementary number theory to help so thanks anyways! I don't think I reached that far yet I searched all the theorem/corollaries in my chapter that can help me with this question but found none.. :(